# Spring Boot / Security - Cannot customize security when running on embedded Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-7

I've got a Spring Boot application that won't run on embedded tomcat, but runs fine on a hosted tomcat install. The setup worked prior to Spring Boot 1.0.0.RELEASE, but I can't determine what changed.

Essentially what is happening is that my app has no concept of a "ServletContext", and thus certain pieces blow up on load. I've seen a few other posts mentioning that the order of configurations (specifically security) being instantiated matters, but I can't seem to fix the issue. Removing the @Configuration annotation from SecurityConfig.java lets the application load, but then I can't customize the security as needed. Also, adding @Order to that class doesn't have any effect.

The entire project is hosted [here](https://github.com/Lemniscate/boot-stack-demo), with the relevant pieces being [pom.xml](https://github.com/Lemniscate/boot-stack-demo/blob/master/pom.xml), [DemoApplication.java](https://github.com/Lemniscate/boot-stack-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/lemniscate/stack/boot/DemoApplication.java) & [SecurityConfig.java](https://github.com/Lemniscate/boot-stack-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/lemniscate/stack/boot/config/SecurityConfig.java)

Any help would be appreciated

**Stacktrace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:683)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:142)
    at com.github.lemniscate.stack.boot.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.<init>(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d9a689bd.CGLIB$defaultServletHandlerMapping$23(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d9a689bd$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$aa3e36b5.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d9a689bd.defaultServletHandlerMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: Your `@EnableApiResources` is the culprit, I think. Here a chat room if you want to discuss: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56869/24598959

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We tracked this down in a chat to a combination of `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` and using JPA for `UserDetails` (either of which work on their own). There's a Spring Security issue open to track at least part of this: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2661.

Workarounds: don't use `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` or don't use JPA for `UserDetails`, or possibly make the `UserDetailsService` initialize lazily when used, not when injected into the authentication builder.

Comment: So, I tried pulling the UserDetails object out with no luck -- though the UserDetailsService implementation still uses a Spring Data repository, but that should be okay, right?


Also tried lazy instantiation of the service but no dice.


Removing `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` works, but then I can't use the @Secured annotations. Any work around to enable those another way? Haven't tried subclassing `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` but I have a feeling I'll end up in the same boat...

Comment: `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` is definitely recommended, but I couldn't get your code to work even with that. I might noodle around with it some more.

Comment: That'd be awesome, thanks. The only other solution I can think of would be a custom annotation + AOP advice, which really is subpar to your guys' excellent work.

Comment: Here's an interesting observation. If you remove the `SecurityProperties` `@Bean` your app starts up (no idea what it's supposed to do so I don't know if it's working). That's surprising, but probably not unreasonable (`@ConfigurationProperties` also have to be instantiated very early). Since you aren't actually using the `SecurityProperties` it shouldn't hurt to remove it (or put it in a separate `@Configuration`).

Comment: Brilliant! I'll try this out when I get a few to verify there's no other side effects. Thank you so much!

Comment: Quick update: removing SecurityProperties fixed all my woes. Hopefully I can dig in to figure out why though. Was a bit maddening